# Python Local Variable Scope

Tags: python

I have a final exam coming up and this is the only question I am unable to answer correctly:

> Question 4
>
> ```
> word = 'off'
> prev = ""
> for letter in word:
>     if prev == "";
>         prev = letter
>         out = ""
>         continue
>     elif letter == prev:
>         prev = letter
>         out = letter
>         break
>     else:
>         prev = letter
>         out = word[0]
> print(out)
> ```
>
> a) o
>   b) f
>   c) of
>   d) "" (the empty string)
>   e) none of the above

When I was trying to solve it I thought the answer was going to be "none of the above" because `out` is defined in local variable scope and would no longer exist out of each part of the `if` statement. When I ran the code in the compiler to check my answer I found that the correct answer is b. Can someone explain why the local variable scope allows this answer to be correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This problem is not related to variable scope: All variables live in the global scope, as there are no additional objects like functions or classes involved. (If the code was put in a function, names assigned within the function would have local scope.) I believe, the question is only about control flow and name bindings.

Comment: Read about [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Comment: Python doesn't have block scope; the `for` and `if` statements don't have their own scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable is not declared in a function or class, it is instead declared in the global scope.

You can read more about it here:

- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables
- https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Comment: The code works just fine in a function or a class too. Python just doesn't have block scope at all.